# Response sending 200 instead of 403

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-authentication

I have a middleware checking if the user is logged in via firebase. If firebase wasn't able to authorize the user, it sends a message with a 403 status code.

Here's my code:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import firebase from "../config/firebase/index";

async function authMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const headerToken = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!headerToken) {
    return res.send({ message: "No token provided" }).status(401);
  }

  if (headerToken && headerToken.split(" ")[0] !== "Bearer") {
    res.send({ message: "Invalid token" }).status(401);
  }

  const token = headerToken.split(" ")[1];

  try {
    await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({ message: "Could not authorize" }).status(403);
  }
}

export = authMiddleware;
```

When I make a request to a route, this middleware gets called. I tried sending over a faulty jwt and the response I got was `message: "Could not authorize"`, but the status code was `200` instead of `403`.

When I change the return status code to `401` the response gives the correct `401` status.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make the status code be `403`? (I tried in postman and chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) method returns response with default status of 200 before the `status(403)` updates it. You must use `status()` before sending response to set the status:

```
res.status(403).send({ message: "Could not authorize" });
```